# Sizing buttons for a 10:90 Percentage split

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

Within Android Studio, I have got two buttons that are evenly sized across the bottom of an activity. How can I make button # 1 about 10 % with button # 2 at 90 % to fill out the bottom? Here is what I have so far...:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

        <!-- Button # 1-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="UP" />

        <!-- Button # 2-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWMS"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorActiveBtn"
            android:text="XYZ" />

    </TableRow>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use a `layout_weight` property of `LinearLayout` children...

Answer (score 0):

You can add weight to your buttons while using `weightSum` attribute on the parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    ....
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <Button
        ...
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        ...
        android:layout_weight="9"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the 2nd button's weight:

```
android:layout_weight="9"
```

Since the 1st has `android:layout_weight="1"` you will get what you want.